# How to consume xml in wcf?

Tags: java, c#, android, xml, wcf

I want to run post method on wcf. I am also developing an android application and dont know how to format the data on java and how to accep this on wcf side.

My wcf method:

```
    public string GetURL(ExtensionsType[] Extensions, Header Header, int Amount, int CurrencyCode, string CustomerId, short CustomerIdType, short IdAndVOption, string OrderID, PreAuthOptionType PreAuthOption, string TerminalCode, short operationType)
    {          

        GetUrlRequestType keyReq = new GetUrlRequestType();

        keyReq.Extensions = Extensions;  
        keyReq.Header = Header;
        keyReq.Amount = Amount;
        keyReq.CurrencyCode = CurrencyCode;
        keyReq.CustomerId = CustomerId;
        keyReq.CustomerIdType = CustomerIdType;
        keyReq.IdAndVOption = IdAndVOption;
        keyReq.OrderID = OrderID;
        keyReq.PreAuthOption = PreAuthOption;
        keyReq.TerminalCode = TerminalCode;
        keyReq.operationType = operationType;

        GetUrlResponseType keyResp = new GetUrlResponseType();

        keyResp = reff.PSP_GetUrl(keyReq);

        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(keyResp);
    }
```

Now it is accept all the paramaters seperately i want to make it accept parameters as xml.

Interface side:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, )]
string GetURL(ExtensionsType[] Extensions, Header Header, int Amount, int CurrencyCode, string CustomerId, short CustomerIdType, short IdAndVOption, string OrderID, PreAuthOptionType PreAuthOption, string TerminalCode, short operationType);
```

How can i modify this methods as take xml as parameters. And how to prepare an xml on java side according these parameters.

Comment: Why all of these tags?

Comment: Which one ? (Türkçe cevap yazabilirsiniz).